# OpenCV predict takes too much time and freezes the screen

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I have tried following code to predict using `CameraBridgeViewBase`.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = mGray.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
    }

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    if (mJavaDetector != null)
        mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2,
                new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());

    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

    if (facesArray.length == 0) {
        return mRgba;
    }
    if (faceType == PREDICT && canPredictNext) {
        canPredictNext = false;
        Mat m = mGray.submat(facesArray[0]);

        int[] label = new int[1];
        double[] d = new double[1];
        faceRecognizer.predict(m, label, d);
```

Here screen freezes until this Log has been gets printed. May I know how to avoid this?

```
        Log.v(TAG, "ID: "+label[0]+", confidence: "+d[0]);
        canPredictNext = true;
    }
    return mRgba;
}
```

**This `predict` freezes screen minimum 3 sec.**

predict in FaceRecognizer class.

```
public void predict(Mat mGrey, int[] label, double[] confidence) {
    predict(mGrey.getNativeObjAddr(), label, confidence);
}
```

And native predict method declared as

```
public native void predict(long mats, int[] integer, double[] d);
```

JNI method for this predict is

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_opencv_test_FaceRecognizer_predict
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jlong images1, jintArray label, jdoubleArray confidence) {
    Mat &mGr = *(Mat *) images1;
    jint *labelBody = (*env).GetIntArrayElements(label, 0);
    jdouble *confidenceBody = (*env).GetDoubleArrayElements(confidence, 0);
    int &myLabel = labelBody[0];
    double &myConfidence = confidenceBody[0];
    model->predict(mGr, myLabel, myConfidence);
    (*env).ReleaseIntArrayElements(label, labelBody, 0);
    (*env).ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(confidence, confidenceBody, 0);
}
```

How can I increase the speed of predict and resolve the predict issue?

Comment: Use a second thread. Doing the calculations on a different thread doesn't block the main thread and therefore doesn't crash your app.

Comment: Calling it in background + skipping frames, only call 2-3 times per second + resizing the input gray image to smaller dimensions may help you getting the required boost.

Comment: `onCameraFrame` this method also in background thread only friend. Now also app doesn't crash, it just freezes for some seconds. @LunarWatcher

Comment: @Gunaseelan If you use a second thread, it will solve the issue as main thread blocking is a crash reason. Doing it async helps preventing thread blocking on the main thread and therefore avoid the crash. The problem is syncing data between the async thread and main thread

Comment: @ZdaR... Thank you... This works now... Add your comment as answer. I will accept it.